# Add foreign key using Firedac without SQL

Tags: firedac

It's easy enough to create a table using a TFDTable component, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to create a referential constraint without resorting to SQL. Since this solution is intended to be database agnostic, I would prefer to avoid this, over implementing separate solutions for SQL Server, Oracle, Teradata and MySQL.

Is it even possible to create FKs using firedac, or do I need to grow my own?

Comment: `CreateTable` can generate indices.

Comment: That is true. Creating a primary key or any other index was easy enough to figure out. But a foreign key is not just an index - it is a key to a referenced table to enforce referential integrity, which you cannot specify with an FD index. Unless I've missed something?

Comment: I know what is FK. And you haven't missed anything. Creating FKs is not implemented. Even if it could have been (for master detail connected dataset objects).